# decoding binary data when structures include strings

Tags: go

Im trying to parse a binary protocol using golang
I am using encoding/binary library's Read function to map the data to a struct

My struct looks like this

```
type getSessionsResponseIPDR struct {
    RequestID     uint16
    VendorID      string
    Name          string
}
```

However it doesnt look like the binary.Read function does not handle strings ending in '\0'

Is there another way to read this object

Comment: The Read command is returning invalid type

Comment: I don't think we can help you without seeing any of the code in question. Did you pass your `getSessionsResponseIPDR` object as a pointer? Please show the code that reads it. It also might be that the `encoding/binary` package doesn't support strings, please check if [`Size`](https://godoc.org/encoding/binary#Size) returns `-1`

Comment: I think it doesn't support strings, see here: https://play.golang.org/p/BwCPGsEqQ52

Answer (score 1):

It seems like this isn't possible with `encoding/binary`, as it only supports fixed-size objects. This means that strings aren't supported at all.

If you don't have control over the sending end, you must implement it "manually", as in reading from the connection and interpreting the read bytes correctly.

If you have control over the sending end, you can use something like [`encoding/gob`](https://godoc.org/encoding/gob) or [`encoding/json`](https://godoc.org/encoding/json).